# Why is comparing two parameters of a constexpr function not a constant condition for static assertion?

Tags: c++, constexpr

```
constexpr uint32_t BitPositionToMask(int i,int Size){
static_assert(i < Size,"bit position out of range");
return 1 << i;
}
```

this generates:

```
error: non-constant condition for static assertion
```

on GCC 4.6.2 Am I not getting something or is this a GCC bug?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A `constexpr` function can also be invoked with arguments evaluated at run-time (in that case, it just gets executed just like any regular function). See, for instance, this *[live example](http://ideone.com/jwDI9S)*.

A `static_assert()`, on the other hand, strictly requires its condition to be a constant expression that can be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: so since it "could" be a run time function static_assert dosn't like me, oh and hey Andy you seem to answer all my questions.

Comment: @PorkyBrain: lol, I swear I'm not doing it on purpose (in fact I am not really answering a lot of questions lately)

Answer (score 0):

This answer was posted by [odinthenerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893819) (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license) as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17577749/2) to the question [Why is comparing two parameters of a constexpr function not a constant condition for static assertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577749). Reposted here to conform to the site's Q&A format.

---

> If the values are known at compile time, they can be passed as template parameters and it works as intended.
>
> ```
> template<int i,int Size>
> constexpr uint32_t BitPositionToMask() {
>   static_assert(i < Size,"bit position out of range");
>   return 1 << i;
> }
> ```