# Can't use function parameter of a constexpr function in a constant expression

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, constexpr-function

Consider the following code:

```
static constexpr int make_const(const int i){
    return i;
}

void t1(const int i)
{
    constexpr int ii = make_const(i);  // error occurs here (i is not a constant expression)
    std::cout<<ii;
}

int main()
{
   t1(12);
}
```

Why I have an error on make_const call?

---

**UPDATE**

But this one works:

```
constexpr int t1(const int i)
{
    return make_const(i);
}
```

However, this not:

```
template<int i>
constexpr bool do_something(){
    return i;
}

constexpr int t1(const int i)
{
    return do_something<make_const(i)>();   // error occurs here (i is not a constant expression)
}
```

Comment: Well because in the general case, `i` isn't `constexpr` in `void t1(const int)`.

Comment: how can I make it constexpr, then?

Comment: making it a template argument is your only option

Comment: Your update does compile (though it does something completely different), what do you mean it doesn't work? (the `const` is useless)

Comment: @Marc Glisse - Indeed... Question updated.

Comment: I want to forward that "12" to "do_something" template argument.

Comment: Must we guess at the error?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - updapted

Comment: There is no direct way to do what you want to do. This feature/limitation is probably the most frequently asked question about constexpr.

Comment: related: [using `static_assert` when function args are constexpr after inlining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275300/constexpr-static-assert-and-inlining), which is what I was looking for when google took me to this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is comparing two parameters of a constexpr function not a constant condition for static assertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577749/why-is-comparing-two-parameters-of-a-constexpr-function-not-a-constant-condition)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A `constexpr` function and a `constexpr` variable are related, but different things.

A `constexpr` variable is a variable whose value is guaranteed to be available at compile time.

A `constexpr` function is a function that, if evaluated with `constexpr` arguments, **and** behaves "properly" during its execution, will be evaluated at compile time.

If you pass a non-`constexpr` `int` to a `constexpr` function, it will not magically make it evaluated at compile time.  It will, however, be allowed to pass the `constexpr`ness of its input parameters through itself (normal functions cannot do this).

`constexpr` on functions is a mixture of documentation and restriction on how they are written and instructions to the compiler.

The reason behind this is to allow the same function to be evaluated both at compile time, and at run time.  If passed runtime arguments, it is a runtime function.  If passed `constexpr` arguments, it may be evaluated at compile time (and will be if used in certain contexts).

Note that `consteval` may be what you are looking for for a function.  But maybe not.

You are getting errors because by passing in runtime values, you cannot get a compile time value out.

There are ways around this.  My favorite is a `std::variant` of `std::integer_constant`; you can pick which is active at runtime, then `std::visit` to get the compile time constant.  The downside is that this can generate a *lot* of code really easily.

```
template<auto I>
using constant_t=std::integral_constant<decltype(I),I>;
template<auto I>
constexpr constant_t<I> constant_v={};
template<auto...Is>
using var_enum_t=std::variant<constant_t<Is>...>;
template<class Indexes>
struct var_enum_over;
template<class Indexes>
using var_enum_over_t=typename var_enum_over<Indexes>::type;
template<class T,T...ts>
struct var_enum_over<std::integral_sequence<T,Is...>>{
  using type=var_enum_t<Is...>;
};
template<std::size_t N>
using var_index_t=var_enum_over_t<std::make_index_sequence<N>>;

template<std::size_t N>
var_index_t<N> var_index(std::size_t I){
  constexpr auto table=[]<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)->std::array<N,var_index_t<N>>{
    return { var_index_t<N>(constant_v<Is>)..., };
  }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
  if (I>=N) throw 0; // todo: something better
  return table[I];
}
```

(Probably has typos).

Now you can:

```
auto idx=var_index<5>(3/* 3 can be runtime */);
std::visit([](auto three){
  // three is a compile time value here
}, idx);
```

Answer (score 12):

One important difference between `const` and `constexpr` is that a `constexpr` can be evaluated at compile time.

By writing `constexpr int ii = make_const(i);` you are telling the compiler that the expression is to be evaluted at compile time. Since `i` is evaluted at run-time, the compiler is unable to do this and gives you an error.

Answer (score 1):

Because t1() is not a constexpr function, the parameter i is a runtime variable... which you can't pass to a [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) function. Constexpr expects the parameter to be known at compile time.

Comment: Making t1 constexpr wouldn't change anything.

Comment: Yes, I test your suggestion. Same old story.

Comment: @MarcGlisse t1() is not correctly formed to be a constexpr function, I wasn't suggesting making it so would correct the problem.

Comment: @praxos1977 - see updated question. Your suggestion is wrong.

Comment: @tower120, I wasn't making a suggestion. I was pointing out that you can't pass a runtime variable to a constexpr function. TAS obviously worded his answer better than I did.