# Recursive template parameter pack programming

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'm pretty new to C++ template programming. I'd like to design a function `element` such as *e.g.*

1. `element<3, 3, 3, 3, 3>` will return 3
2. `element<3, 3, 2>` will fail an assertion

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <cstdlib>

   namespace meta
   {       
     template<typename T>
     constexpr T element(T x)
     {
       return x;
     }

     template<typename T, typename... Ts>
     constexpr T element(T x, Ts... xs)
     {
       constexpr T oth = element(xs...);             // $C$
       static_assert(oth == x, "element Mismatch");
       return x;
     }

     template<int... DIMS>
     void get_elements()
     {
       std::cout << "elements " << element(DIMS...); // $A$
     }
   }

   int main(int argc, char ** argv)
   {
     meta::get_elements<2, 3, 4>();                  // $B$

     static constexpr int D1 = 3, D2 = 3;

     meta::get_elements<D1, D2>();
   }
   ```

But GCC with `std=c++14` is failing with

> In instantiation of ‘constexpr T meta::element(T, Ts ...) [with T = int; Ts = {int, int}]’:
>
> $A$:   required from ‘void meta::get_elements() [with int ...DIMS = {2, 3, 4}]’
>
> $B$:   required from here
>
> $C$: error: ‘xs#0’ is not a constant expression
>
> $C$: error: ‘xs#1’ is not a constant expression

I'd like to exploit recursion to perform an equality check on each template argument in the list, and return one of them if they're all equal.

Comment: Pardon, just fixed a couple of errors

Comment: I was editing asap. foo is `get_elements`. I apologize

Comment: please create a [MCVE]. Don't make us play the guess game

Comment: are you limited to C++11?

Comment: No, in facts the c++ standard is not a constraint

Comment: Now the error message doesn't match the code. Take your time, no one is in a hurry ;)

Comment: Thank you, Quentin. Error updated, lines highlighted

Comment: Finally found a good [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569309/c11-constexpr-function-pass-parameter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parameters are not `constexpr`.

You might use `std::integral_constant` to bypass that

```
namespace meta
{       
  template<typename T, T V>
  constexpr std::integral_constant<T, V> element(std::integral_constant<T, V>)
  {
    return {};
  }

  template<typename T, T V, typename... Ts>
  constexpr std::integral_constant<T, V> element(std::integral_constant<T, V> x, Ts... xs)
  {
    constexpr auto oth = element(xs...);             // $C$
    static_assert(oth() == x(), "element Mismatch");
    return {};
  }

  template<int... DIMS>
  void get_elements()
  {
    std::cout << "elements " << element(std::integral_constant<int, DIMS>{}...); // $A$
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution in C++17:

```
template <int Head, int... Tail> struct element
{
    static_assert((... && (Head == Tail)), "missmatch elements");
    static constexpr auto value = Head;
};

template <int... I> constexpr auto element_v = element<I...>::value;

auto test()
{
    // element_v<3, 3, 1>; // assert fail

    constexpr int A = 3, B = 3;
    return element_v<3, 3, A, B>;
}
```

See it on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/dPYQLh)

Answer (score 2):

Or pre-c++17 (no recursion):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <type_traits>


namespace meta
{     

  template <bool...>
  struct boolpack { };

  template <bool... Bs>
  struct all_of: std::is_same<boolpack<Bs..., true>, boolpack<true, Bs...>> { };


  template<int FIRST, int... DIMS>
  constexpr void get_elements()
  {
      static_assert(all_of<DIMS==FIRST...>::value, "!");
      std::cout << "elements " << FIRST;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  static constexpr int D1 = 3, D2 = 3;

  meta::get_elements<D1, D2>();
  //meta::get_elements<D1, D2, 2>(); //fail
}
```

[[see it live]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GoSOOTVpaxoR5tW2)

**Edited**: `all_of` inspired by Jarod42.