# Extracting first parameter of __VA_ARGS__

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose that I have a macro:

```
#define FOO(a, ...) if (a) foo(a, ## __VA_ARGS__)
```

This works well:

- `FOO(a)` will be transformed to `if (a) foo(a)`
- `FOO(a, <some_parameters>)` will be transformed to `if (a) foo(a, <some_parameters>)`

Is it possible to modify this macro, so only the first parameter of `__VA_ARGS__` (if exists) passed to `foo`? So, I need:

- `FOO(a)` to be transformed to `if (a) foo(a)`
- `FOO(a, b, <some_parameters>)` to be transformed to `if (a) foo(a, b)`

I've tried to solve this with the same idea as `BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE` has, but it turned out this macro returns `1` for `BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE()` (empty arguments), which is not expected (I expected `0`).

Note, that I need a solution, where `b` and `<some_parameters>` are evaluated only when `bool(a)` is `true`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading Macro on Number of Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments)

Comment: @Frank: thanks for finding that question, based on that I could solve the problem.

Comment: Do you really need MACRO ? simple overload seems to do the job.

Comment: @Jarod42: yes, macro is needed, because I need to lazily evaluate FOO's parameters (I mean, in real code, I only call `foo`, when certain condition is true. If that condition is false, then `foo` is not called, and its parameters are not evaluated).

Comment: @geza Are the type of `a`, `b` and `<some_parameters>` all same ?

Comment: @Hiroki: no, they are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose a variadic macro with a generic lambda as a solution.
The Important points are as follows:

- It is difficult to pass both `a` and `__VA_ARGS__` to a lambda as passed arguments in macro because when `__VA_ARGS__` is empty

  ```
  [](){...}(a, __VA_ARGS__)
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  [](){...}(a,)
  ```

  and this `,` leads compilation error. 
  **Thus we split the first and second arguments of `FOO` into the captured and the passed ones respectively as follows.**
  Then we can use a generic lambda in the macro even if `__VA_ARGS__` is empty.

  ```
  [a](){...}(__VA_ARGS__)
  ```
- The size of `__VA_ARGS__` can be evaluated at compile-time as `constexpr auto N`. Then we can use `if constexpr` to separate function calls.
- We can also apply *if statement with initializer* which is introduced from C++17 for `if(a)`.

Then the proposed macro is as follows.
This also works for you.

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YW68wdsJDA4cAchK)

```
#include <tuple>

#define FOO(a, ...)                                                           \
if(const bool a_ = (a); a_)                                                   \
[a_](auto&&... args)                                                          \
{                                                                             \
   const     auto t = std::make_tuple(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); \
   constexpr auto N = std::tuple_size<decltype(t)>::value;                    \
                                                                              \
   if constexpr( N==0 ) {                                                     \
       return foo(a_);                                                        \
   }                                                                          \
   else {                                                                     \
       return foo(a_, std::get<0>(t));                                        \
   }                                                                          \
}(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem with this approach is that `args` are always evaluated. I need a solution, where the evaluation of `args` can be controlled. Sorry, I didn't specified this in the question (but a comment describes this). Now I'll put this info into the question. But I'll give you an upvote anyways :)

Comment: It’s very elegant work. Out of curiosity, why is `t` not `constexpr` as well?

Comment: @JonHarper thx. I think that `constexpr auto t` shows compile error if `__VA_ARGS__` exists because constexpr variables must be guaranteed to be initialized at compile-time and `args` are not initialized by a constant expression. I found similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569309/c11-constexpr-function-pass-parameter).
But the types of `args` and `N` are determined at compile-time because generic lambdas are essentially same with function templates and these are template parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233547/how-does-generic-lambda-work-in-c14 .

Comment: @geza *if statement with initializer* which is introduced from C++17 seems to be useful for me. How about [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QoFC7bnRFAj41I52) ? Could you point out it if I still misunderstand the problem :) . If this provides a one of the solution, I will edit my answer whether you accept my answer or not.

Comment: @Hiroki: Nice work! I feel a little bit dumb, as the surrounding if is kinda trivial to add, I don't know why I didn't think of it :) Please add the `if` here as well, and I'll accept your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21371401/8157187), I could solve the problem:

```
#define PRIVATE_CONCAT(a, b) a ## b

#define CONCAT(a, b) PRIVATE_CONCAT(a, b)

#define GET_100TH( \
    _01, _02, _03, _04, _05, _06, _07, _08, _09, _10,  \
    _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, _17, _18, _19, _20,  \
    _21, _22, _23, _24, _25, _26, _27, _28, _29, _30,  \
    _31, _32, _33, _34, _35, _36, _37, _38, _39, _40,  \
    _41, _42, _43, _44, _45, _46, _47, _48, _49, _50,  \
    _51, _52, _53, _54, _55, _56, _57, _58, _59, _60,  \
    _61, _62, _63, _64, _65, _66, _67, _68, _69, _70,  \
    _71, _72, _73, _74, _75, _76, _77, _78, _79, _80,  \
    _81, _82, _83, _84, _85, _86, _87, _88, _89, _90,  \
    _91, _92, _93, _94, _95, _96, _97, _98, _99, PAR,  \
    ...) PAR

#define HAS_PARAMETER(...) GET_100TH(placeholder, ##__VA_ARGS__, \
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)

#define FIRST_PARAMETER_WITH_PREPENDED_COMMA0(...)
#define FIRST_PARAMETER_WITH_PREPENDED_COMMA1(a, ...) , a

#define FIRST_PARAMETER_WITH_PREPENDED_COMMA(...) CONCAT(FIRST_PARAMETER_WITH_PREPENDED_COMMA, HAS_PARAMETER(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)

#define FOO(a, ...) if (a) foo(a FIRST_PARAMETER_WITH_PREPENDED_COMMA(__VA_ARGS__))
```

Comment: This is ugly... Are you sure you want to poison your codebase with *this*?

Comment: @YSC: Yes, it's ugly. Boost's preprocessor library is ugly as well. But if you have a better solution, feel free to share with us :)

Comment: @geza generate your code using python instead of the C++ preprocessor?  :)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: this solution is fine. Even if it's ugly, the interface is OK (I don't care about ugliness which is behind the interface. I care about interface, and usability. A comment can explain the ugliness inside). Using python for this task is unnecessary, and would make building more complex. But thanks for the idea anyway :)