# Is constexpr superfluous for a static constant wrapper object?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I have a constructor template (in non-template class) with a non-type template parameter, which is deduced from `std::integral_constant`. Is there a need to declare an object of `std::integral_constant` type that will be passed into the constructor `constexpr`? It seems superfluous.

Also I see that [C++ standard libraries make](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_place) objects for tag dispatching `constexpr`. Is there a real need for that? Since not a tag object is used at compile-time but its type.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23569309/1541563)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an instance of your class in compile-time code aka `constexpr` or `consteval` the constructor must be declared `constexpr` (or be implicit constexpr).

The code you posted as link contains no explicit constexpr constructors. But it defines `constexpr` variables.

Could you post your code?

Comment: The constructor is not `constexpr`. It's just a template, instantiation of which will be used at runtime.