# Integral template parameter. error: use of 'this' in a constant expression

Tags: c++

I tried to find a similar answered question in SO but without success.
Question is why it is considered as error to use at compile time known at compile time value of template parameter of known at compile time type? Common sense tells me, that this code can be OK. What is wrong in this case?
Thanks!

```
#include <array>

using Cont = std::array<int, 2>;

class A
{
    Cont a_ = {};

public:
    int& at(bool first)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof(a_) / sizeof(int) == 2); // OK
        static_assert(a_.size() > 1); // error: non-constant condition for static assertion. error: use of 'this' in a constant expression
        return a_[first ? 0 : 1];
    }
};
```

[at compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/RJ37Gx)

**UPDATE**: it looks like dublicate but may be not because in the question under [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577749/why-is-comparing-two-parameters-of-a-constexpr-function-not-a-constant-condition) the speech is about run-time evaluation, but here looks like a_.size() can be evaluated in compile-time.

**UPDATE2** More clear example (after considering answers and comments)

```
#include <array>

using Cont = std::array<int, 2>;

// OK
void checkSize(const Cont& b)
{
    static_assert(b.size() == 2);
}

class A
{
    Cont a_ = {};

public:
    constexpr void checkSize() const
    {
        Cont b = {};
        static_assert(b.size() == 2); // OK
        static_assert(sizeof(a_) / sizeof(int) == 2); // OK
        static_assert(a_.size() == 2); // error: non-constant condition for static assertion. error: use of 'this' in a constant expression
    }
};
```

shows that the problem in *this* is involved to evaluate *a_.size()*. But why it is needed there, while *a_* is known by compiler as non-virtual type and *size()* can be evaluated in compile time, may be is another question, so I'll check first answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577749/why-is-comparing-two-parameters-of-a-constexpr-function-not-a-constant-condition

Comment: @PasserBy it looks like dublicate but may be not because in the question under link the speech is about run-time evaluation, but here looks like *a_.size()* can be evaluated in compile-time.

Comment: Why do you assume size() can be evaluated at compile time?

Comment: Consider `auto pa = new std::array<int, 2>{};` followed by `static_assert(pa->size() > 0);`. Though we know that this assertion will be always true, compiler cannot evaluate it at compile time since a pointer is involved. Which is in your case as well, namely `this` pointer.

Comment: @Moia std::array::size() is declared as constexpr and returns integral template parameter value. compiler sees the problem in *this*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::array::size`, even though a `constexpr` function, isn't a `static` function. This means it requires an object instance to be invoked.

In this particular case, `at` isn't `constexpr`<sup>†</sup>, therefore `this` isn't either and in turn `_a`. Since `_a` isn't `constexpr`, the result of `_a.size()` isn't `constexpr` too.

<sub>† Even if it is, the body still [isn't considered `constexpr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577749/why-is-comparing-two-parameters-of-a-constexpr-function-not-a-constant-condition).</sub>

Comment: Is *static_assert(decltype(a_)().size() == 2);* can be assumed as workaround?

Comment: @wtom sure, as long as the array elements have `constexpr ` default constructor.

Comment: and trivial destructor, I suppose

Answer (score 3):

`a_` is a member of the class `A`.

`a_.size()` is a simplification of `this->a_.size()` because size is not a static function, which means that in order to access `a_`, you have to access `this`.

`this` is a pointer to a class A and is NOT a compile time constant making your `static_assert` fail.

Using template is probably easier :

```
template<int N>
class B {
    std::array<int, N> a_;
    public:
    int& at(bool first)
    {
        static_assert((sizeof(a_) / sizeof(int)) == 2, "Sizeof operator"); // OK
        static_assert(N > 1, "Size method"); // No problem here
        return a_[first ? 0 : 1];
    }

};
```